# Shorter than target vector path algorithm

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory, np-hardness, shortest-path

Consider a generalisation of the shortest path problem on directed graphs with weights in $\mathbb{Q}^k$. Formally, the input is a graph, a source state $s$, a target state $t$, and an objective vector $\vec{o}$. The goal is to determine whether there is a path from $s$ to $t$ in the graph whose cost $\vec{c}$ (obtained by summing the weights at each transition) is smaller or equal than $\vec{o}$ (componentwise).

It is easy to show that the problem is in NP. The problem with equality $\vec{c} = \vec{o}$ is NP-complete (from [this paper](http://www.numdam.org/item/ITA_1997__31_5_429_0.pdf)). On the other hand, the problem with inequality $c \le o$ for dimension one is solvable in polynomial time using the shortest path algorithm.

Is there a polynomial time algorithm for the inequality version of the problem?

Comment: This is a standard problem called the multi-objective shortest path problem, and as noted in the the answers, it is NP-Hard for even two dimensions via a reduction from Subset Sum or Knapsack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is NP-hard, even in just two dimension, by reduction from the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

Consider a 0-1 knapsack instance with $n$ items, where the weight of the $i$th item is $w_i$ and its value is $v_i$.  Build a graph with $n+1$ vertices, with one edge from the $i$th vertex to the $i+1$st vertex of weight $(0,0)$ and another of weight $(w_i,-v_i)$.  Now to test whether there exists a solution to the knapsack instance with total weight $\le W$ and total value $\ge V$, check whether there exists a path in the graph from the first vertex to the last vertex whose cost is $\le (W,-V)$.